# What is dm.mlstat.com?

Tags: website, web

I'm responsible for a large number of web caches, and something that is almost at the top of reports by hits requested by quite some margin is "dm.mlstat.com" - yet I can't figure out what it is!

Whois just gives the details of a private registration company.

The site is hosted in a /18 netblock belonging to "Elron Technologies", and the IP routes through Israel.

The URL accessed most often by far is http://dm.mlstat.com/update/dm/wg.php which returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 06 Dec 2012 18:16:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=30
X-Server: wadyn1
Content-Length: 59
<UpdateResponse><Interval>86400</Interval></UpdateResponse>
```

Any clues!?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's malware or a virus. If it is coming from your network I'd remove the host

http://www.securelist.com/en/descriptions/17134445/Trojan.Win32.Sefnit.dhi?print_mode=1

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a url search.mlstat.net on ask.com, the site is probably a statistics collector that is even used by some malware (but may be used for legitimate sites as well).